# How to group only one field in the kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, grouping

How to group only one field?

When I group an item I want to disable the grouping of other fields.
I create a demo
http://dojo.telerik.com/UgoyO/35

it should not be possible to group the second field!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated your fiddle. What i did is adding a function which listens to the group event and prevents adding more than one group.

http://dojo.telerik.com/UgoyO/38

Comment: that's not what I asked.
I would like to group any column, the others have disabled the pool.
It could be the name, but also the age.

Comment: @Federico what you mean by the others have disabled the pool?

Comment: it should not be possible to group the second field!

Comment: @Federico ok I think I got what you want. Check the update!?

Comment: this is one of the possible right solutions.
you deserve a vote for the solution.
I'd like to find out if there are other possible solutions

Comment: @Federico it will be hard to find a better solution than this, I think. This is a fine solution for your needs.

Comment: is it possible with mvvm?

Comment: Yes sure create a data source in your viewmodel and bind the source to it